# Mistake in reasoning regarding initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y(x)$ be the solution to the initial value problem:

$y''y=(y')^2$

$y(0)=1, y'(0)=2$

I am very close to the right answer, but there is a mistake in my reasoning, and I would like to know where:

Let's define $z=y'$.

$y''=z \frac{dz}{dy}$.

Therefore z $\frac {dz}{dy}y=z^2$

$z dz=\frac{z^2}{y}dy$

$\frac{dz}{z}=\frac{1}{y}dy$

Therefore $lnz=lny$, meaning the derivative is identical to the original function.

And therefore $y = e^x$.

I know that the right answer is $y=e^{2x}$, so I am close, but there is a mistake somewhere. I suspect it is in the very last step, but I am not sure what the right alternative should be…

Thank you!

Comment: Is $y=e^2x$ a typo for $e^{2x}$?

Comment: Werren't you expecting to find a general solution **with two arbitrary constants**? How were you planning to use the initial values?

Comment: It's my second week doing differential equations: now that you mention it, yes, but I am not quite there yet.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the constant of integration. You should obtain ln z = ln y + k where k is a constant. From the boundary conditions k = ln 2.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dz}{z}=\frac{dy}{y}\implies \ln z=\ln cy $$

Thus $$y'=cy$$

$$y=Ke^{cx}$$

The initial condition results in $$y=e^{2x}$$